# How do I retry reading a locked database with C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have several C# applications that all use the same SQLite database (contains some user information). Only one of them has to write to it, but all of them now and then have to read.

While the one application is writing, if the other applications happen to want to read something, I get the Database Locked exception.

Is fine and all, and as expected, but how do I go around the retrying of the read? `while (exception) try again` is probably a naive and nasty solution..

I'm thinking there's simply some `System.Core.Sqlite` option about retries I'm missing.
Google gave me some solutions that involved copying and deleting the database or killing processes; but I think those are quite.. unrelated.

Comment: This looks relevant: https://github.com/michael-wolfenden/Polly

Comment: You could try with a timeout since when the database is locked it will be on busy state and may throw a timeout from a secondary app, so set a connection with a short timeout like 100ms or so.

Comment: If you want to design your own retry logic it might be a good idea to follow this pseudo-code pattern: `for(int i = 1; i <= maxRetries; i++){try{read}catch(LockedException){if(i == maxRetries){log that the max retries was hit}else{thread.sleep(baseRetryTime * i);}}}`
Note: you probably don't want to use `thread.sleep()`
Notenote: you may want to use something like `Math.Pow(baseRetryTime, i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite automatically retries when you have set a [busy timeout](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout).

Comment: Will it help waiting database will become available for writing, to avoid 'attempt to write a readonly database' error (`SQLiteErrorCode.ReadOnly`) ?

Comment: @apdevelop That error message has a different cause (that the connection was not opened with write permissions).

Comment: In my specific case file is blocked (and database became readonly) for a few seconds by external 3rd party process, which makes a copy (hot backup) of database file. Trying to open database with `PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE` doesn't helps too, the database file is still blocked during a copying.

Comment: @apdevelop That is a diferent problem. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If possible you may want to investigate using [Write-Ahead Logging (WAL)](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

Using WAL mode, a writer and readers do not block each other. However, there is still only one writer allowed, but this is not a concern as you are only writing to the DB using a single application.

Additionaly, you could catch this the System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException and repeat the query until it works :-)

If brute force doesn't work you're not using enough :-)